# The pronunciation of French "e"

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

Does [this table for French “e” pronunciation](http://funshore.com/web/french/pronounce_e.htm) look OK to you?  Please definitely point out any errors!

The same contents as of this table are also found at the end of this question on this page.

#### Background

I am new to French and am trying to discern any patterns in the various pronunciations of "e" and related groups of letters.  I looked up each word in the dictionary for the phonetic notation and placement in the right column.  Anything that seemed exceptional, I've marked with an asterisk (*).  A dot (•) represents attempts at seeing what was going on (and not any accepted syllabification).

Sorry that it is not a traditional type of question.  I hope there will be many helpful comments.  Thank you.

PS.  (26 Nov 2014)  Thanks for the comments.  I tried to reflect them in the table.  This resulted in some entries occurring more than once.   The number sign (#) marks them.

---

### List of rules and examples

#### 1. Silent

paradigm

- *ils jouent

‘e’ at the last position absolute

- rouge [ruʒ], une école [ekɔl], une chaise [ʃεz], vite [vit]
- une patte [pat], un arbre [arbr]
- un musée [myze]

v+c+"e"

- ache•ter [aʃte], appe•ler [aple]
- Alle•magne [almaɲ], bibe•ron [bibrɔ̃], un change•ment [ʃɑ̃ʒmɑ̃], un mate•las [matla], un boulange•rie [bulɑ̃ʒri]
- #apparte•ment [apart(@)mɑ̃], #juste•ment [ʒyst(@)mɑ̃]

#### 2. [ə] ([mid-central](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-central_unrounded_vowel))

[ə] paradigm

- de [də], je [ʒə], le [lə], ne [nə]
- *Monsieur [məsjø], *nous faisons [- fə-]

[ə] c+"e"•c

- pre•nais [pʁə.nɛ]
- ce•la [səla], un che•val [ʃ(ə)val], de•main [dəmε̃], ge•nou [ʒənu], me•ner [məne], pe•tit [p(ə)ti], pre•mier [prəmje], une se•maine [s(ə)mεn], Mercre•di [mεrkrədi]
- #apparte•ment [apartəmɑ̃], #juste•ment [ʒystəmɑ̃]

#### 3. [e] é ([close-mid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel))

[e] paradigm

- un été [ete], le thé [te], un défilé [defile], je suis arrivé, j'ai mangé

[e] at the last position except for a mute consonant

- manger [mɑ̃ʒe], parler [parle]
- mangez, parlez
- il est
- les [le], ses [se]
- chez [ʃe], un nez [ne]

[e] end of verb

- je parlai [-e], je parlerai [-e]
- j'ai [-e]

[e] c+"e"•cc

- une e•ssence [esɑ̃s], ble•sser [blese]

[e] c+"ei"

- #ensei•gner [ɑ̃seɲe], #pei•ner [pene]

#### 4. [ɛ] è ê ([open-mid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel))

[ɛ] paradigm

- dès [dε], près [prε]
- une mère [mεr], bière [bjεr]
- être [εtr], bête [bεt], même [mεm], une tête [tεt]

[ɛ] at the last position absolute

- bai [bε], gai [gε], lai [lε], mai [mε], un rai [rε]

[ɛ] at the last position except for a  mute consonant

- un ballet [balε], un cabaret [kabarε], un duvet [dyvε], un jouet [ʒwε], *et [e]
- laid [lε], un fait [fε], le lait [lε], sait, tait, mais [mε], un palais [palε]

[ɛ] end of verb

- je parlais [-ɛ], je parlerais [-ɛ], ils parlaient [-ɛ]
- j'aide [-ɛ], je t'aime [-ɛ]

[ɛ] "e"+c
* le mer• [mεr], du sel• [sεl], avec• [avεk], un appel• [apεl], sept• [sεt], mer•ci [mεrsi], der•nier [dεrnje], un ex•pert [εkspεr], pres•que [prεsk], une élec•tion [elεksjɔ̃], une ouver•ture [uvεrtyr]

[ɛ] "e"+c+"e"

- le sexe• [sεks], une veste• [vεst]

[ɛ] "e"+cc+"e"

- belle• [bεl], telle• [tεl], un dilemme• [dilεm], une chienne• [ʃjεn], une cuvette• [kyvεt], une sagesse• [saʒεs], une vaisselle• [vɛsɛl ]

[ɛ] "e"+"ille"

- une abeille• [abεj], une bouteille• [butεj], un conseil• [kɔ̃sεj], vieille• [vjεj]

[ɛ] "ai"+c+"e"

- un/une aide• [εd], une chaise• [ʃεz]

[ɛ] "ei"+c+"e"

- la neige• [nεʒ], treize• [trεz], une enseigne• [ɑ̃sεɲ], une peine• [pεn], un peigne• [pεɲ], la reine• [rεn]

[ɛ] c+"ei"

- #ensei•gner [ɑ̃sεɲe], #pei•ner [pεne]

#### 5. Nasal, etc.

[ɑ̃] nasal initial

- ennuyer [ɑ̃nɥije], ensemble [ɑ̃sɑ̃bl], vendre [vɑ̃dr]
- embrasser [ɑ̃brase], un membre [mɑ̃br], novembre [nɔvɑ̃br], le printemps [prε̃tɑ̃]

[ε̃] nasal final
* ancien [ɑ̃sjε̃], un chien [ʃjε̃], européen [ørɔpeε̃]

[a] -emment

- récemment [resamɑ̃], apparemment [aparamɑ̃], évidemment [evidamɑ̃]
- *une femme [fam]

[ø] eu

- peu [pø], bleu [blø], adieu [adjø]
- deux [dø], dangereux [dɑ̃ʒʀø]
- un nœud [nø]
- elle veut [vø]
- #heureux [ørø], #un peureux [pørø]

[œ] eu

- une peur [pœr], une odeur [ɔdœr]
- jeune [ʒœn], une heure [œr]
- le beurre [bœr]
- un deuil [dœj]
- un œuf [œf], une sœur [sœr]
- œil [œj]
- ils veulent [vœl]
- #heureux [œrø], #un peureux [pœrø]

[y] eu

- *eu [y], *eût [y]

Comment: appar**a**te•ment [apartəmɑ̃] → apparte•ment [apartəmɑ̃] → appartement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjunction *et* `[e]` is definitely an `[e]`, you're correct.

Words in the “[ə] open vs. closed” section seem quite correct except “apparte•ment” that belongs in a category of its own, category which includes mostly adverbs like “justement”, for instance. It's the `@` [SAMPA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symboles_SAMPA_fran%C3%A7ais) symbol, and frankly you could merge them into the mute section.

Also :

> [e] end of verb
>
> - je parlai [-e]
> - je parlerai [-e]
> - j'ai [-e]

These can belong to the “[ɛ] end of verb” paradigm as well. Both pronunciations are correct and widely used, even though as you correctly indicate, theoretically the `[e]` paradigm should be used. Technically though, the third person plural form “ils parlaient” use a “[ɛ] end of verb” paradigm and not a `[e]`.

For this one : heureux `[ɶrø]`, the common pronunciation is more `(ə)r(ə)` to be honest; or more precisely `2 r 2` if you use the [SAMPA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symboles_SAMPA_fran%C3%A7ais) notation for French sounds again.

> c+"ei"
>
> - ensei•gner [ɑ̃seɲe]
> - pei•ner [pene]

are more a `[ɛ]` paradigm, though that will very much depend on the person you're talking to.

Also:

- *une femme [fam]

is correct. And

- *Monsieur [məsjø]
- *nous faisons [- fə-]

are theoretically at the right place.

> In a nutshell you will find very high local differences in France and French-speaking countries, and they will greatly vary from word to word. You may have different responses from different French people ;) and that's normal.
>
> If you're looking for something very descriptive and clear, you might want to use the **CNRTL Morphalou** tool available online : http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/ along with a full SAMPA terminology cheat sheet.
>
> Please note as well that some pronunciations have evolved from the early dictionaries you can find online or offline, and will still likely evolve. Good luck !

*PS : the CNRTL site is down sometimes, just be patient ;)*

Comment: Thank you.  ‘Appartement’ and ‘justement’ are assimilated into the mute column (with @, a SAMPA symbol, inserted into what is otherwise another notation scheme).  These words remain in the [ə] column as well because that’s what wordreference.com says.

Comment: I did not duplicate ‘je parlai’ etc. in the [ɛ] column in reliance on [e] being said to be ‘theoretically’ correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most of it's wrong. The e in some cases, like the final e and in celà, is supposed to be represented by a ligated œ as in œuf and bœuf. Also, the é and -er are supposed to be represented by the symbol that represents the short i, as in the English 'pin'. As well, the a without a circumflex and in the beginning or middle of a word is usually pronounced like the a in the English 'pan', represented by the ligated ae. The standard phonetic transcription is so bizarre it is surreal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).